# Redux dispatch multiple action synchronously one after another

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have multiple actions to be dispatch on page load for getting products, categories, history etc.
so on app.js i am dispatching multiple action. but the values one of the action depends upon another action here is the example

App.js

```
componentDidMount( ) {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(getAllCurrency());  
    dispatch(getAllProducts());  
}
```

as you can check both are working simultaneously and later data is added to global state properly.

But as currencies are many and they take time to add it to global state 
and the component later is using currency.
Hope this clear the question pretty much 
any help would be highly appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: It depends a bit, are you familiar with `redux thunk`? https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: yes i am and currently using it. actually the problem is when i am using product action then i am using redux thunk to get global state via **getState** but the problem is same when using getState then the currency is undefined.

Comment: I am using redux-thunk only for getting global state in action but the problem as i have mentioned is that the global state doesnot have currency data but if i checked  the redux dev tool the global state has data but it might be possible that the data is provided later and the other dispatch is working simultaneously hope it clear the question

Comment: Yes, that means your dispatch(getAllCurrency()) is in fact asynchronous (or has async side effects). If you setup it properly with redux thunk, your dispatch can return a Promise so that you can do dispatch(getAllCurrency()).then(() => dispatch(getAllCurrency());

Comment: Alternatively, don't fetch the currency data as an async action, but structure it something like `fetchData().then((data) => { dispatch(saveData(data); dispatch(getAllProducts()); } )`

Comment: Althogh i was done as i find the issue, but I tried your approach in some other component in order just to learn. can you please let me know the issue with this approach. `dispatch(getAllCurrency()).then(() => dispatch(getAllCurrency());` The problem can be little described is that getAllCurrency function also dispaching another action inside and we also want to resolve promise as well. Take a look below.

Comment: `export const getAllCurrency = ( currency, current_cart ) => ( dispatch ) => {
  
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

      
        dispatch(setCurrency( currency ));
        
        resolve(true); 
  
    });

  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anybody still looking for an answer for making a synchronous request based on dispatch for functional component do this below you will get promise which you later can apply then method and execute afterward code

```
const getCurrency = () => async dispatch =>{ return dispatch(getAllCurrency())}
```

and later you can do this
const response = await getCurrency();
*** so on***